# undefined method 'signed_in?' in cucumber BDD when using "assert ! controller.signed_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

I am working on cucumber BDD on rails-3 application.

When I use **"assert ! controller.signed_in?"** in step_definition
And When I run "cucumber"
Then I got this error  **"undefined method 'signed_in?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"**

Why is it not going into controller-helper (signed_in? is defined in sessions_helper)?

When I tried by "`assert ! SessionsController.signed_in?`"

```
Error : undefined method `signed_in?' for SessionsController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

And When "`assert ! SessionsHelpers.signed_in?`"
Error : undefined method `signed_in?' for SessionsHelper:Module (NoMethodError)

In my Sessions_helper:

```
def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue, and solved it by adding `World(SessionsHelper)` to the bottom of the Cucumber steps file (there's probably a better place to put it).

On a side note, you'll probably encounter other issues relating to cookies and sessions as it appears Cucumber does not support these between requests. So for example, you won't be able to test `signed_in?` after performing a redirect/submitting to the login form.